# Parsing error at AngularJS

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, parse-error

I have the following error at console

```
"Error: [$parse:syntax] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.12/$parse/syntax?p0=Detail&p1=is%20an%20unexpected%20token&p2=11&p3=carrental%09Detail.hostDescription&p4=Detail.hostDescription
```

That means

```
Error: $parse:syntax
Syntax Error

Syntax Error: Token 'Detail' is an unexpected token at column 11 of the expression [carrentalDetail.hostDescription] starting at [Detail.hostDescription].
```

But in my php in retrieving data at mysql database

```
$carrentalhost = $this->master_model->getRecords('carrentalhost', ['carrentalId' => $carrentalId])[0];
        if(!empty($carrentalhost['hostImage'])){
        $hostImage= base_url() . 'resources/carrentals/carrentalhost/' . $carrentalhost['hostImage'];
        }  else {
            $hostImage=null;
        }
        $categoryId = $this->master_model->getRecords('module_category', ['module_id' => 8], 'id')[0];
        $mobileNumber = $carrentalhost['hostMobile'];
         $resultArray = [       
            'hostName' => $carrentalhost['hostName'],
            'hostEmail' => $carrentalhost['hostEmail'],
            'hostDescription' => $carrentalhost['hostDescription'],
            'price' => $carrentalhost['price'],
            'selectedDates' => $carrentalhost['availableDates']
        ];        
        if (!empty($resultArray)) {
            $responseArray = array(
                'result' => $resultArray,
                'success' => true);
            return $this->set_response($responseArray, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK);
        }
```

I checked at my PHP code and I can retrieve correct data from the database.

At my AngularJS side,

```
var loadCarrentalDetails = function () {
        var query = {};
        var loadCarrentalDetailsReq = CarrentalResource.loadCarrentalDetails(query);
        loadCarrentalDetailsReq.success(function (loadCarrentalDetailsRes) {
            $scope.carrentalDetail = loadCarrentalDetailsRes.result;                
        });
        loadCarrentalDetailsReq.error(function () {

        });
    }
    loadCarrentalDetails();
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Please show us the HTML.

Comment: Yes my html code has issue.

Answer (score 0):

Check your response because response may not be valid JSON Object.

Valid JSON

```
[
  {"field":"value1"},
  {"start-time":"2017-07-12T00:34:36.000Z"}
]
```

Invalid JSON

```
[
  {"field":"value1"},
  {start-time:2017-07-12T00:34:36.000Z}
]
```